# How to display all values in a combobox by recordset (Access 2010)

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba, ms-access-2010

I have the problem that the combobox in access 2010 displays just 1249 values of the 1278. Is there a possibility to increase the max number of values in a combobox in access?

Here is a code sample:

```
If not rs.EOF Then
    rs.MoveFirst
    frm.FName.RowSource = ""
    frm.FNameLux.RowSource = ""

    Do Until rs.EOF
        If rs![id] <> -1 And rs![id] <> -2 Then
            If (rs!KID <> 2 And rs!KID <> 8) Then
                If IsNull(rs![Name]) = False Then
                    frm.FName.AddItem rs![Name] & ";" & rs![id]
                    Debug.Print rs!Name 'The program writes all values in the combobox, but when I look in the form, I don't see all values
                End If
            End If

            If (rs!KID = 2 Or rs!KID = 8) Then
                If IsNull(rs![Name]) = False Then
                    frm.FNameLux.AddItem rs![Name] & ";" & rs![id]
                End If
            End If
        End If
        rs.MoveNext
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End If
```

`rs` is the recordset. Is there any idea how to solve it or what I have to do?

Comment: Does the combobox stop after the *first* 1249 items, or are random items missing?

Comment: @Andre In `debug.print` a see all values without stopping after a corresponding item.

Comment: @Andre So, I identified that the problem occurs when I defined the combobox with 2 columns. But I didn't find a solution. `ColumnCount` is set to 2 `ColumnWidths = 15cm;0cm`, `BoundColumn=2` and `Row Source Type = value list`

Comment: Sorry, I mean `BoundColumn=1`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the `RowSource` property for `RowSourceType = Value list` is limited to 16bit integer length (2^15 = 32768) or a bit below.

Test code for a 2-column combobox:

```vb
Private Sub btValues_Click()

    Dim i As Long

    DoCmd.Hourglass True

    Me.cboValues.RowSource = ""
    For i = 1 To 5000
        Me.cboValues.AddItem "Number " & Format(i, "0000") & ";" & i
    Next i

    DoCmd.Hourglass False

    Debug.Print Len(Me.cboValues.RowSource)

End Sub
```

The combobox is filled up until "Number 1991", output is `32739`.

So the problem is not the number of rows, but the total string length. If I shorten the text, it goes up to "Nr 2604" (32744 chars).

You'll have to use `RowSourceType = Table/query` to show all items.

**Edit**

Create queries as rowsource for the comboboxes. As far as I can see, there is nothing in your code that cannot be done in a WHERE clause.

E.g. for `FName`

```sql
SELECT Name, id
FROM yourTable
WHERE id <> -1 AND id <> -2
  AND KID <> 2 AND KID <> 8
  AND Name IS NOT NULL
```

If your VBA code could not be recreated in SQL, you'd have to insert the recordset rows you want into a temp table, and use this table as rowsource.

Comment: thanks for your answer. How can I define my Stored Procedure in a "table/query" type?

Comment: Could you make me a code example? I tried du write the SELECT statement into `.RowSource` but the Combobox remains empty.

Comment: I suggest making an actual saved query with this SQL. Test this query, then use its name as rowsource. If it doesn't work, please add a screenshot of the property sheet of the combobox (tab Data).